# Make an 8 by 8 grid have the correct FEN notation. Like a Chess Board

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i made a 8 by 8 grid in Unity just by using DrawLine and for loops.
My next step is to make each box have its official combination, for example the bottom-left should be 1a and the top-left should be 8a...
My plan was making again for loops inside the existing loops but it just gives errors.
Could someone give me some tips on how this could be achieved

```
private void DrawChessboard()
{
    //8 units of 1 meter to the right
    Vector3 widthLine = Vector3.right * 8;
    //8 units of 1 meter up
    Vector3 heightLine = Vector3.forward * 8;

    //makes the 8 by 8
    for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        Vector3 start = Vector3.forward * i;
        Debug.DrawLine(start, start + widthLine);
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            start = Vector3.right * j;
            Debug.DrawLine(start, start + heightLine);
        }
    }

    //This draws the selection
    if (selectionX >= 0 && selectionY >= 0)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(
            //Bottom left to top right
            Vector3.forward * selectionY + Vector3.right * selectionX,
            //this is the end point. +1 to make it diagonal
            Vector3.forward * (selectionY + 1) + Vector3.right * (selectionX + 1));

        Debug.DrawLine(
            //Bottom left to top right
            Vector3.forward * (selectionY +1) + Vector3.right * selectionX,
            //this is the end point. +1 to make it diagonal
            Vector3.forward * selectionY  + Vector3.right * (selectionX + 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point out where exactly you get errors / what is not working as expected? What happens instead? What exactly do you mean by `make each box have its official combination` ... is there a Dictionary or something like that?

Comment: @derHugo that code just makes a 8*8 grid and displays it inside the camera range in Unity. What im trying to do it make it "Forsyth-Edwards Notation" (FEN) viable. To do that i need to make each square in the grid have its own value. For example the bottom left shoud be 1a, the bottom right 8a, top right 8f. My plan was to make 2 for loops one saying horizontal squares goes from 1 to 8 and vertical sqaures go from a to f. But i cannot manage to do it

Comment: the question is **how**? .. using `Text` or `TextMesh` components / `Sprites` / ... ? Where is your method called? e.g. in `OnDrawGizmos` you could use `Handles.Label(position, "Text");`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure where your method gets called exactly but since you use `Debug.DrawLine` I guess it is some kind of editor method or script. So I'll make my example in [`OnDrawGizmos`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html)

As said you can use [`Handles.Label(position, "Text")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.Label.html) to draw a text as debug label in the SceneView.

In order to get the correct chars I simply use

```
nextChar = (char)(currentChar + 1);
```

(To make it complete I just also added the black and white fields)

so it might look like

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChessFieldDebug : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        //8 units of 1 meter to the right
        var widthLine = Vector3.right * 8;
        //8 units of 1 meter up
        var heightLine = Vector3.forward * 8;

        const char firstLetter = 'a';

        // Only for you I also added black and white fields
        var isBlackField = false;
        var black = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.25f);
        var white = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.25f);

        //makes the 8 by 8

        //rows
        for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            var start = Vector3.forward * i;
            Debug.DrawLine(start, start + widthLine);

            //colums
            for (var j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
            {
                var currentLatter = (char)(firstLetter + j);
                start = Vector3.right * j;
                Debug.DrawLine(start, start + heightLine);

                // this flag alternates between black and white
                isBlackField = !isBlackField;

                // Since you draw the last line but don't want a field added skip if over 8
                if (i >= 8 || j >= 8) continue;

                var centerOfField = Vector3.forward * (i + 0.5f) + Vector3.right * (j + 0.5f);

                // Draw text label on fields with colum char + row index
                Handles.Label(centerOfField, currentLatter.ToString() + (i + 1));

                Gizmos.color = isBlackField ? black : white;
                Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.forward * (i + 0.5f) + Vector3.right * (j + 0.5f), new Vector3(1, 0.01f, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

---

Make sure to either put this in an `Editor` folder or use pre-processor tags arround like

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class ChessFieldDebug : MonoBehaviour
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // ...
    }
    #endif
}
```

to avoid Exception when you build your project